# PerfMon / MMC Hangs

Tags: perfmon, windows

I'm "playing" with PerfMon - it's the firs time I've ever spent any real time in it.  Everything is fine and then I will perform an action (like trying to bring up the properties of a counter I have added to the real-time monitor graph) and it hangs.

A look at the Task Manager doesn't give any clues.

Any ideas what the root cause might be, or where I should start looking?

Comment: Keeps happening with me also, its so irritating.

Answer (score 1):

This also happens to me. It's related to Chrome for some unknown reason.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=76985

I should add that you can end task for the mmc in task manager, and go back in, and it will usually work. Closing chrome will cause the ghost "Properties" dialog to go away.